# Click a Button Just two times

Tags: android

I'm looking around internet to have the possibility to press a button just two times. I'm implementing the code for a poker game, then the player should press the button one time to show the card and the second time to change it. How can I do it. The only thing I found was to click it one time (that I don't need because it has also to change a card, but just one time). That's what I have for the first button:

```
backgroundA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    int randomInt1 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());
                    int drawableIDA = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt1, -1);
                    backgroundA.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDA); 

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a `flag` that will check for click, if you click it once the flag will be true and if you click it again your statement inside your `OnClickListener` will get executed.

**sample:**

```
boolean flag = false;
boolean flag2 = false;

backgroundA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                if(!flag){ flag = true }
                else
                {
                    if(flag2) { flag = false; }
                    else
                    {
                       int randomInt1 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());
                       int drawableIDA = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt1, -1);
                       backgroundA.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDA); 
                       flag2 = true;
                    } 

                } 

            }
        });
```

Comment: Use an int instead of a boolean and count the clicks. Use switch to decide what to do

Comment: But with the switch I have to introduce also the enumerate class. Is it not too long to do?

Comment: I try to use a counter and then I use a loop to stop it but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok I did something similar but I have a bug. Can i show it to you?